# Replace 0x80~0xFF in a String to other value

Tags: java, string, replace, unicode

I need to modify the string but the "replace" does not work on everything that starts from 0x80.

Example of received data in hex `31 32 33 81 82 35`.
But the StringBuilder I get is "313233818235" (which I expect to see "3132333435").
Any idea how to fix it? I'm using "windows-1252" charset.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner (new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(),charset))).useDelimiter(mDelimiter);

                    rxMsg = (scanner.next()).replace("\u0081\u0082","\u0034");

                    byte[] byteArray = rxMsg.getBytes(charset);

                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    for(byte b: byteArray) {
                        stringBuilder.append(String.format("%02x", b));
                    }
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what is sent through the socket connection and what is received? Also, did you try debugging?

Comment: @dan1st, I just edited my post. Hope it make things clear. The "replace" works for everything below 0x80.

Comment: So you get binary dta and want to see the hex representation of the binary numbers without trailing 0x80? Why do you use `Reader`/`Scanner`, then?

Comment: And you want to remove the the byte 0x80 at the beginning?

Comment: Digits, Euro € and maybe comma. Sure not an amount is meant?

Comment: @dan1st, I'm working on an App communicates with a server sending string with STX/ETX delimiter, I've to use Scanner to get the data. However, I need to replace some part of it. I need to replace some of the 0x80 only, not all.

Comment: 0x81 and 0x82 probably refer to a byte in the Windows-1252 encoding. If you specify "Windows-1252" as *charset*, they have already been replaced with other Unicode codepoints by the time you process the string. 0x82 becomes U+201A, but 0x81 is not valid.

Comment: @Codo, this is it! I should use \U201A instead, and I just realize i dont need 0x81. Thanks!